# 3TB Drive doesn't always show up initialized in USB3 Dock

Tags: hard-drive, usb, gpt

Have a perfectly fine 3TB GPT drive which shows up in most of our machines when direct connected and often in docks. But, we've used it in a few new USB3 docks and sometimes it will show up as UN-initalized. Usually, connecting directly to the board will allow it to show up. Any reason there would be a conflict with the USB3 dock and the 3TB drives?